# How to alter a prototype's method without overriding it?

Tags: javascript, methods, prototypal-inheritance

I need to do the following:

```
function Shape (width, height) {
    var self = this;
    self.width = width;
    self.height = height;
    self.calculateSurface = function () {
        return (self.width * self.height);
    };
};

function Circle (radius) {
    //make sure width == height == radius.

};

Circle.prototype = new Shape;
Circle.prototype.constructor = Circle();

function Triangle (base, height) {
    var self = this;
    Shape.apply(self, arguments);
};

Triangle.prototype = new Shape;
Triangle.prototype.constructor = Triangle();

var circle = new Circle(5);
var triangle = new Triangle(5, 8);

alert(circle.calculateSurface());
alert(triangle.calculateSurface());
```

Both calls to the base prototype method must return the area of the caller, but without overriding the method.

How can I make it return (width * height) / 2 for triangle and (radius * radius) * pi for circle without overriding it?

Thanks for your time and all best!

**EDIT:**

```
var output = document.getElementById('output');

function Shape(width, height) {
    var self = this;

    self.width = width;
    self.height = height;
};

Shape.prototype.calculateSurface = function () {
    return (this.width * this.height);
};

function Rectangle(width, height) {
    Shape.apply(this, arguments);
};
Rectangle.prototype = new Shape;
Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;

function Triangle(base, height) {
    Shape.apply(this, arguments);
};
Triangle.prototype = new Shape;
Triangle.prototype.constructor = Triangle;

Triangle.prototype.calculateSurface = function () {
    return ((this.width * this.height) / 2);
};

function Circle(radius) {
    Shape.apply(this, arguments);
};
Circle.prototype = new Shape;
Circle.prototype.constructor = Circle;

Circle.prototype.calculateSurface = function () {
    return((this.width * this.width) * Math.PI);
};

// testing
var outputStr = "";
var outputArr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    var rectangle = new Rectangle(i + 1, i + 2);
    var triangle = new Triangle(i + 1, i + 2);
    var circle = new Circle(i + 1);
    outputArr[i] = rectangle;
    outputStr += "Rectangle width: <b>" + rectangle.width + "</b> height: <b>" + rectangle.height + "</b> area: <b>" + rectangle.calculateSurface() + "</b><br />";
    outputArr[i + 1] = triangle;
    outputStr += "Triangle base: <b>" + triangle.width + "</b> height: <b>" + triangle.height + "</b> area: <b>" + triangle.calculateSurface() + "</b><br />";
    outputArr[i + 2] = circle;
    outputStr += "Circle radius: <b>" + rectangle.width + "</b> area: <b>" + circle.calculateSurface() + "</b><br /><br />";
};

output.innerHTML = outputStr;
```

It works correctly, I hope I understood it right.
**Thanks again!**

Comment: `Circle.prototype.constructor = Circle` omit the parens – you shouldn't invoke the constructor function there.

Comment: another little thing — you don't have to create reference to `this` as to `self` unless you need to preserve scope inside of other function, and that you could also do by using `Function.prototype.bind`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't define method (`calculateSurface`) of the custom type (a.k.a. “class”) on the instance, so, not:

```
self.calculateSurface = function () {
    return (self.width * self.height);
};
```

But:

```
Shape.prototype.calculateSurface = function () {
    return (this.width * this.height);
};
```

Then you need to *shadow* the property that is higher in the prototype chain. So the lookup will first look at `Triangle.prototype` and only then at `Shape.prototype` – using the first property it finds.

```
Triangle.prototype = new Shape;
// Note that you don't need to put parens after Triangle.
// You only set property to point at constructor function itself,
// not to the value constructor returns when invoked. (Also, constructor 
// should be invoked with `new` operator, not just with parens).
Triangle.prototype.constructor = Triangle; 
// now shadowing Shape.prototype.calculateSurface
Triangle.prototype.calculateSurface = function () { 
  // custom code here
}
```

Same goes for the `Circle`.

Comment: Thanks gruzzly! I think I got it. And it works fine. I will post the update.